# How to install “desktop sharing” in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: remote-desktop

In the Ubuntu Dash Menu, when a search for “desktop sharing” found no installed. 
When I try to launch desktop sharing in Ubuntu 18.04 a problematic option appear as mentioned in below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > sharing > screen sharing:
[image: Screen sharing]

Comment: i already on the screen sharing. problem is desktop sharing NOT LUNCH IN ubuntu

Comment: Do you mean the client or the server? the client is remmina.